# Reuse select expressions in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-5, linq-to-entities

I have some complex business definitions that I'd like to define once and reuse them in Linq to Entities and also use them in other expressions that build upon it.

My attempt is below, and this worked when I was originally passing the `ConvertOrderDetailsToViewModel` a `List`, but I want to perform this on an `IQueryable`, which results in the error:

`LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Decimal Invoke(OrderDetail)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Is there a way to achieve this natively (without 3rd party libraries)?
Looks like from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29511860/reusable-functions-for-use-with-linq-to-entities), you can define these functions in the database itself, and then call them from C#, but again, looking to do this solely in C# code if possible.

Also came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986877/how-can-i-reuse-expressions-within-linq-statements) which looks like it works for a `Where` expression, but when I try to implement it for my `select` expression, I get the this error, which I get, because I am trying to assign the expression to a decimal.

`Cannot implicitly convert type Expression<Func<OrderDetail, decimal>> to 'decimal'`

Here's the expression function:

```
public static Expression<Func<OrderDetail, decimal>> calcQtyNeedOD = (od) => (od.OrderedQuantity - od.PickedQuantity);
```

View model creation method that calls this function:

```
public List<AllocationNeedViewModel> ConvertOrderDetailsToViewModel(IQueryable<OrderDetail> qryShipOrderDtls, List<int> itemIdsToExclude, bool boolGroupViewModelByItemAndRemnant)
{
    var qryAllocNeedVMTEST = 
        from od in qryShipOrderDtls
        select new AllocationNeedViewModel()
        {
            WorkReleaseHeaderId = od.OrderHeader.WorkReleaseHeaderId.Value,
            OrderHeaderId = od.OrderHeaderId,
            OrderDetailId = od.Id,
            ItemId = od.ItemId.Value,
            ItemDescription = od.Item.Description,
            IsInventoryTracked = od.Item.TrackInventory,
            QtyNeed = calcQtyNeedOD(od),
            QtyRemain = 0,
            QtyAllocated = 0,
            IsAllocated = false
        }
        ;
        return qryAllocNeedVMTEST.ToList();
}
```

To Make this more complex, there are other properties that I also want to have a reusable expression for, which would also use this first expression...i.e.

```
public static readonly Expression<Func<OrderDetail, decimal>> calcQtyRemainOD =
    (od) => calcQtyNeedOD.Compile().Invoke(od) - calcQtyAllocatedOD.Compile().Invoke(od);
```

**UPDATE #1**

**SEE UPDATE #2...this solution does NOT work!**

Though so far no one has been able to provide a native way to reuse select expressions *across* queries, I did find a partial solution that works in being able to reuse them *within* the same query. Once you project/assign an expression to an entity's property, you can (unlike in T-SQL) then specify that property as part of another subsequent property expression.

Example - this shows the full expressions for each property projection. In this example, `QtyRemain` is essentially just `QtyNeed - QtyAllocated`. I was re-specifying those again in the `QtyRemain` assignment:

```
public List<AllocationNeedViewModel> ConvertOrderDetailsToViewModel(IQueryable<OrderDetail> qryShipOrderDtls, List<int> itemIdsToExclude, bool boolGroupViewModelByItemAndRemnant)
{
    var qryAllocNeedVM = qryShipOrderDtls
        .Select(od => new AllocationNeedViewModel() //Get all Work Order Detail Needs for Work Release
        {
            QtyNeed = (od.OrderedQuantity - od.PickedQuantity), 
            QtyAllocated = (od.AllocatedInventories.Count == 0 ? 0 : od.AllocatedInventories.Where(ai => ai.StatusId < _AllocatedInventoryProcessedStatus).Sum(ai => ai.AllocatedQty)), 
            QtyRemain = (od.OrderedQuantity - od.PickedQuantity) - (od.AllocatedInventories.Count == 0 ? 0 : od.AllocatedInventories.Where(ai => ai.StatusId < _AllocatedInventoryProcessedStatus).Sum(ai => ai.AllocatedQty))
        }
        );
        return qryAllocNeedVM.ToList();
}
```

Instead, you can simply use the already defined properties in that `QtyRemain` property assignment, like so:

```
public List<AllocationNeedViewModel> ConvertOrderDetailsToViewModel(IQueryable<OrderDetail> qryShipOrderDtls, List<int> itemIdsToExclude, bool boolGroupViewModelByItemAndRemnant)
{
    var qryAllocNeedVM = qryShipOrderDtls
        .Select(od => new AllocationNeedViewModel() //Get all Work Order Detail Needs for Work Release
        {
            QtyNeed = (od.OrderedQuantity - od.PickedQuantity), 
            QtyAllocated = (od.AllocatedInventories.Count == 0 ? 0 : od.AllocatedInventories.Where(ai => ai.StatusId < _AllocatedInventoryProcessedStatus).Sum(ai => ai.AllocatedQty)), 
            QtyRemain = this.QtyNeed - this.QtyAllocated
        }
        );
        return qryAllocNeedVM.ToList();
}
```

Though this is not a full solution to my original question, it is a partial solution that gets you some of the benefits desired.

**UPDATE #2**

I was wrong on UPDATE #1. Though this works and compiles and seems to generate SQL, it is not correct. The returned value of `this.QtyNeed` when being used in subsequent expressions always results to `0`. :(

Comment: Take a look at [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit)

Comment: Thanks @IvanStoev, but trying not to use third party libraries for now if at all possible. Seems like a lot of these end up getting abandoned after a short period, then don't work when you upgrade your project to the next .net framework, and then you'r stuck having to retrofit a bunch of code.

Comment: @ChadRichardson You can write the code to do what it does yourself, if you prefer, but you'll need to do more or less the same thing as that code base.  You can of course find other people's implementations as well.

Comment: @Servy, understood. I was just hoping there was a native way to do it in 2017 (things keep changing every year). If that answer is no...then I'll take a look at the third party library route for sure....or create a database view.

Comment: Another option is to use a UDF and call it from your query. That will at least save you from writing everything into a view.

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered the following?:

```
public static Func<OrderDetail, decimal> calcQtyNeedOD = (od) => (od.OrderedQuantity - od.PickedQuantity);

public List<AllocationNeedViewModel> ConvertOrderDetailsToViewModel(IQueryable<OrderDetail> qryShipOrderDtls, List<int> itemIdsToExclude, bool boolGroupViewModelByItemAndRemnant)
{
    return qryShipOrderDtls
        .ToArray()
        .Select(new AllocationNeedViewModel
            {
                WorkReleaseHeaderId = od.OrderHeader.WorkReleaseHeaderId.Value,
                OrderHeaderId = od.OrderHeaderId,
                OrderDetailId = od.Id,
                ItemId = od.ItemId.Value,
                ItemDescription = od.Item.Description,
                IsInventoryTracked = od.Item.TrackInventory,
                QtyNeed = calcQtyNeedOD(od),
                QtyRemain = 0,
                QtyAllocated = 0,
                IsAllocated = false
            }).ToList();
}
```

The original query was trying to execute the Func against the actual database (which won't understand your expression). Since you are not filtering your query (no where clause), return the entire set so that you can project using your local Func.

Comment: The question specifically states that they were doing this, but it has (understandably) become too problematic to always do all of this work in memory, and that it needs to be done on the DB side.  Always materializing every query you do into memory is going to be untenable.

Comment: The original question makes no mention of memory requirements/problems. Only that they would like to keep the business logic in C#.

Comment: Yes, it does, "I was originally passing the ConvertOrderDetailsToViewModel a List, but I want to perform this on an IQueryable,"

Comment: Correct @Servy, Eric I was doing what you stated, but the original qryShipOrderDtls brings back a TON of columns from multiple tables, so the whole point of trying to do this in IQueryable is to reduce that data load and memory by only pulling back these few columns.